How does Fedora encryption affect partitions, devices and mountpoints?
Fedora, similarly to other popular popular Linux distros, provides an easy way to set up full disk encryption (FDE). As of Fedora 33, Btrfs has been the default file system (replacing ext4).
I was curious to see a side-by-side comparison of a default installation with/without FDE in Fedora. I thought others might also be interested in this, so I decided to write a Q&A here.

I created two VMs with the same Fedora 40 KDE image and the same default settings, with the only difference being that one of them had FDE (fill disk encryption) activated.

Let's see a side-by-side comparison:

As can be seen, /dev/vda3 is the main partition/device where things differ. Note that if we installed Linux directly on a SATA SSD, we'd have something like /dev/sda* and on an NVMe disk we'd have something like /dev/nvme0n1p* instead.
In the VM with no encryption, for the /dev/vda3 block device it (expectedly) says TYPE="btrfs".
In the VM with encryption, for /dev/vda3 we see TYPE="crypto_LUKS". When the OS boots up and the user enters the correct decryption password or key, the underlying filesystem becomes accessible. Note that there is an additional block device /dev/mapper/luks-4f15... that has similar attributes to the /dev/vda3 device from the no-encryption VM (TYPE="btrfs", LABEL, BLOCK_SIZE, UUID_SUB). That additional block device can also be seen via fdisk, as shown below:

Let's also see how the /etc/fstab files differ:

Almost identical. Only difference seems to be the x-systemd.device-timeout=0 param (I believe 0 here means 'infinity', which kinda makes sense, I guess).
